# Inheritance and method scope in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

In the following example pseudocode:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public void reset() {
        this.clear();
        clear();
    }
    public void clear() { System.out.println("FAIL"); }
};

public class MySpecialPanel extends MyPanel {
    public void clear() { System.out.println("Hello, world"); }
};
```

When calling `(new MySpecialPanel()).reset()` shouldn't both `this.clear()` and `clear()` resolve in the same scope?  Is there any difference between `this.clear()` and `clear()`?

Comment: "resolve in the same scope?" you mean: resolve to the same method call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void reset() {
    this.clear();
    clear();
}
```

In the code above, that calls the same method twice.  There is no difference between `clear()` and `this.clear()`.

You can explicitly call the superclasses method with `super.clear()`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion.  I'm debugging some code that's considerably more complex and I was afraid that I was missing something.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between `this.clear()` and `clear()`.

You have a `MySpecialPanel` object and the `clear()` method on that object is called twice. To call the superclass's clear, you must use `super.clear()`

So, you do something like this --

```
public void reset() {
        clear();
        super.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code:

```
public void reset() {
    this.clear();
    clear();
}
```

both this.clear() and clear() are the same.

this is a keyword for setting the scope of the call inside the class itself
super sets the scope to the class itself and the superclass

Answer (score 0):

Stating the obvious as many have already responded - when you call `clear()` on an object, that object is in scope; when you use `this` you are referring to that same object in context.